# Objective C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm reasonably new to Swift and I'm having real problems with my project, the one step that has been holding me back for days now is that I need to rewrite this block of code in Swift which is currently Objective C. It's driving me mad. The objective C is this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CBCNewsStory *story = self.stories[indexPath.row];
    CBCNewsDetailTableViewController *detailView = [[CBCNewsDetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStory:story];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:true];

}
```

Sounds terrible but all I have managed to do so far is this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

No matter hoe much I try and rewrite the lines inside the function, it just doesn't work, I always get an error on at least two.

If anyone could help, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show your attempt, even if it produces an error?

Comment: It's ok, I was about to post it but someone else solved the problem, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let story = self.stories[indexPath.row]
    let detailView = CBCNewsDetailTableViewController(story: story)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailView, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: That wasn't quite it but close enough, perfect, Problem solved.

Seemed i was being a tad silly and leaving out the "let"

Also to make it work i had to change

    'self.navigationController.pushViewController(detailView, animated: true)'

to

'self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailView, animated: true)'

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my answer to reflect that navigationController is optional.

Comment: You don't need to declare the type of `story` Because `self.stories` is `[CBCNewsStory]` (or at least it should be).